# I start tomcat, my code run fine but after sometime communication link failure exception occurs

Tags: java, tomcat

I start tomcat, my code run fine but after sometime communication link failure exception occurs.

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin failed:
                at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:596)
                at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
                at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
                at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
                at tm.dao.user.UserMasterDAO$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$12662d42.getLogin(<generated>)
                at tm.controller.teacher.BasicController.doSignInPOST(BasicController.java:269)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
                at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
                at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
                at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
        Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin failed:
                at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:96)
                at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1353)
                at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:555)
                ... 36 more
        Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

        Last packet sent to the server was 1 ms ago.
                at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
                at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
                at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
                at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
                at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2871)
                at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3414)
                at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
                at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
                at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2536)
                at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:4874)
                at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(NewProxyConnection.java:881)
                at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:91)
                ... 38 more
        Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
                at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2431)
                at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2882)
                ... 46 more`
```

Comment: Check you db connectivity is getting lost

Comment: Can you show the content of your my.cnf file

Comment: Are you using any lazy type query...

Answer (score 0):

You have not really specified your environment, or shown any of your configuration, but from your stack trace I can see that you are using Spring.

In your spring config xml file, you probably have a "dataSource" bean or something similair to the following:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
```

Try adding the following property to that bean:

```
<property name="validationQuery" value="select 1" />
```

This property is explained here: [DBCP Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html)